# Exception java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry for Urban airship in Android Studio

Tags: android

We are getting  java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry exception in android Studio Compile code Success and at run time we are getting.

We are basically trying to migrate our project from eclipse to Android studio. We removed all other errors which we got during this process but as we are using Urban airship , android studio is giving following exception message when we try to run the project.

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:XXX:assembleDebug]

:XXX:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:XXX:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:XXX:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:XXX:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:XXX:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:XXX:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:XXX:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:XXX:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:XXX:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:XXX:collectDebugMultiDexComponents UP-TO-DATE
:XXX:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':XXX:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/urbanairship/BuildConfig.class

**And .gridle file is :**



apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'



    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.XXX"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 22
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }

}


dependencies {

    compile(project(':urbanairshiplib')) {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'multidex-instrumentation'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are wrapping the Urban Airship SDK eclipse lib project into as a gradle project. Probably because of the eclipse convert tool. Since the SDK was built with Android Studio it already contains the build.gradle file.

Can you instead use the a maven dependency? Try following the directions here - http://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/android.html. If you use the latest SDK version you no longer have to add Urban Airship services, receivers, and providers in your manifest.